# Testing classes organization

Tags: java, android, testing

I am writing test classes in the test module of an Android project, in particular I am writing some functional tests. Now I am in a situation in which I see that a lot of code I am writing should be reusable, now I explain better the situation. Let's think about a test class for a sign up procedure. Now I have a class SignUpTest which has some test methods and some helper methods, called

```
reach<name-of-the-page>Page()
```

Which complete the sign up till the page in the name of the method. This method are not test because they fill the pages of the sign up procedure with correct data not performing any kind of test.

My tests so look like:

```
test<name-of-the-page>Page() {
         reach<name-of-the-page>Page()
         Some tests
}
```

Now I am in the situation that the test of the sign up (depending on the environment in which I want to test testing or staging) should differ in some of these methods, in particular in some reach methods. Which is the best organization of the classes, avoiding redundancy of code, in your opinion?
I absolutely don't want to create two classes with almost the same code except for a couple of methods. I read that inheritance is not a best practices in test cases organization.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar case. I'm using Espresso for Android 2.0 test automation framework. What I did - I created the abstract main test class and put reusable methods inside:

```
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
    public abstract class MainTest<T extends Activity> extends
            ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {

        public MainTest(Class<T> activityClass) {
            super(activityClass);
        }

        @Before
        protected void setUp() {
            super.setUp();
        }

        //put methods you are going to reuse in your test classes here

        @After
        public void tearDown() {
            super.tearDown();
        }
    }
```

Then just extend `MainTest.java` in your test class:

```
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
    public class TestLogin extends MainTest<LoginActivity> {

        public TestLogin() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            super(LoginActivity.class);
        }

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception{
            super.setUp();
        }

        @Test
        public void testLoginUser(){
            //do your test reuse methods from MainTest class
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() {
            super.tearDown();
        }
    }
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, and what about, solving the problem from an higher perspective. I mean what if I create a model layer, populated with some objects that manage some common methods. For instance a SignUp object, abstract class with the common methods, then some subclasses with particular methods for reaching some part of the process in different way. I would like to build some reusable blocks, "semantic" blocks.

Comment: Do you really need it? Will you maintain and refactor it? Will you document all you are going to create for further use by your colleagues? Think it over.

Comment: Yes, I am hired to do exactly that job for now